# how to assign a file to an array of elements which are part of the file

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have a directory which contains `.txt` files. 
In each `.txt` files are lines, under each other. the 2nd line is the **category** line.
A txt file looks like this:

```
id-12345678 // id line
sport // category line
```

A couple of **categorynames** should be excluded form the other categories, like **Offside** and **2019**
I have filtered the array like below:

```
$blogfiles = glob("data/articles/*.txt"); // array with ALL blogfiles
$all_categories = array();

foreach($blogfiles as $blogfile) { // Loop through the blogfiles in the directory   
    $lines = file($blogfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // all lines of the txt file into an array
    $all_categories[] = $lines[1]; // category line (2nd line in txt file)
    $excl_categories = array('Offside','2019'); // contains elements that should be excluded
    $filtered_categories = array_diff($all_categories,$excl_categories); //new filtered array of categories
```

What i need is an array of `blogfiles` in which the categories have been filtered in. I do not know how i can bind the corresponding blogfiles to the filtered array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in_array()` to test each category, rather than using `array_diff()` on the whole array.

```
$excl_categories = array('Offside','2019'); // contains elements that should be excluded
$filtered_files = [];
$filtered_categories = [];
foreach($blogfiles as $blogfile) { // Loop through the blogfiles in the directory   
    $lines = file($blogfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // all lines of the txt file into an array
    $category = $lines[1]; // category line (2nd line in txt file)
    if (!in_array($category, $excl_categories)) {
        $filtered_categories[] = $category;
        $filtered_files[] = $blogfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly i was looking for. Thnx for the solution